# CSV loading from hadoop to hive - scalability issue 20GB/h

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive, presto, tez

I'm looking for a way to speedup loading data from hadoop to hive from where I query with presto. In my workflow I start with single csv file on hadoop.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE src_x (KEY INT, X2 INT)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION "${SRC_X_DIR}"
TBLPROPERTIES('skip.header.line.count'='1');
```

Instant, it creates only view on csv.
Then count all is pretty slow already...

```
select count(*) from src_x;
5000000000
Time taken: 1547.581 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Target tables is prepared as:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS x (KEY INT, X2 INT)
STORED AS ORC
TBLPROPERTIES("orc.compress"="SNAPPY");
```

And loaded:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE x SELECT * FROM src_x;
Loading data to table benchmark.x
Table benchmark.x stats: [numFiles=1, numRows=5000000000, totalSize=18528938624, rawDataSize=17179977764]
Time taken: 19429.984 seconds
```

This single table takes around 5h+ to load from hadoop to hive. Isn't that too long for 103GB csv with two integer columns? Ideally I would aim not just for better scaling on 5e9 but also bigger sets.
Cluster of 10 machines 250GB should handle that. Is it somehow related to my version maybe (`hive-0.14.0.2.2.6.3`) or some custom settings can play a role here?

Comment: There are a lot of factors that effect Hive performance. version 0.14 is not the most recent one, but 5+ hours does seem like a long time for a 10 node cluster.

My questions are:

-Physical nodes or virtualized?

-What is the Hive execution engine, Map-reduce or Tez?

At my last client, _shredding_ a directory of about 1 TB of XML files and loading them to an ORC table took about 40 minutes (4 node, 32 core, 256 GB Ram Cluster)

Comment: @RogierWerschkull Physical nodes, tez. Same data loading in impala parquet completes in minutes.